# C3P0 causing threads to close

Tags: java, c3p0

I have a weird problem. I have an utility class that holds the connection and has function that prepares the statements. The statements are then ran, closed, and everything works fine.

However, when I tried adding a connection pool using ComboPooledDataSource, my threads close. I debugged it and I can see that some queries are executed successfully, but then all of a sudden everything closes and only the c3p0 threads remain running. No exception is thrown.

I tried setting the pool to a single connection to mimic the working code as closely as possible but that also fails. If I set the connection member to the connection from the pool everything works fine, but if I try to using directly from the pool I get the behavior I outlined above.

Here is some sample code:

```
class DBUtilityClass
{
   private java.sql.Connection connection;
   private ComboPooledDataSource connectionPool;

   public void DBUtilityClass()
   {
      connect();
   }

   private void connect()
   {
      connectionPool = new ComboPooledDataSource();
      connectionPool.setDriverClass( "org.postgresql.Driver" ); //loads the jdbc driver   
      connectionPool.setJdbcUrl(urlString.toString());
      connectionPool.setUser(user);
      connectionPool.setPassword(password);
      connectionPool.setAutoCommitOnClose(true);

      connectionPool.setInitialPoolSize(1);
      connectionPool.setMinPoolSize(1);
      connectionPool.setAcquireIncrement(1);
      connectionPool.setMaxPoolSize(1);


   }

   //Version 1 - this works if I set the connection in the constructor 
   //or if I connect the connection manually without using the pool
   public Connection getConnection()
   {
      connection.setAutoCommit(true);
      return connection;
   }

   //Version 2 - This fails
   public Connection getConnection()
   {
      Connection temp = connectionPool.getConnection();
      temp.setAutoCommit(true);
      return temp;
   }

   public PreparedStatement getPreparedStatement(String sql)
   {
      Connection temp = getConnection();
      return temp.prepareStatement(sql);
   }
}
```

Comment: what do you do with your instance of `DBUtilityClass` after you have constructed it and acquired a `Connection`?

Comment: I have a number of threads calling getPreparedStatement, executing the statement, then closing it. I'm running a unit test and it fails in the setup, before it even hits the multi-threaded part.

Comment: But who stores the instance of `DBUtilityClass`? (Maybe post your test code?)

Comment: It's a typical junit test - the test class creates an instance of the utility in the /@Before method and tears it down in the /@After.

Comment: sounds like the pool isn't thread safe. try adding mutexes or synchronized keyword to prevent concurrent access. once your thread has a connection that part should be safe, so you can still do threaded processing afterwards.

Comment: no, the pool is very thread safe. that's it point. (i wrote it.)

Comment: @Hitobat I actually tried rolling my own statement caching (without using a pooling library) but it's fairly complex, thus I decided to use c3p0.

Comment: statement caching is a pain to get right.

Comment: can you try storing your `DBUtilityClass` instance as a static variable rather than relying upon the JUnit init and teardown? Not permanently necessarily, but to debug. i don't see anything particularly wrong with this class (assuming version 1 is gone or commented out and version 2 is available). trying to make the pool as close to a single `Connection` as possible is a bad idea, though, it should work but with min/max of one any leaked Connection (there should be none!) will be an immediate freeze, and you could (shouldn't! but could anyway) hit odd edge cases.

Comment: i'd eliminate that last stanza of config. but it's not your problem -- you saw the issue prior to that. something is up with complexities in your set-up, i think.

Comment: @SteveWaldman i tried increasing the min/max/initial pool size and I'm definitely getting further along. If I set the member connection object to an instance from the pool and use that single instance for everything then everything is fine. I turned off statement caching to eliminate that as a potential problem.

Comment: Oh shoot. I spoke too soon saying everything looks okay. It's not okay at all if you use the function `getPreparedStatement(...)` That function is a Connection leak. So, with `maxPoolSize` of 1, you'd get one PreparedStatement and then the pool would freeze up.

Comment: Get rid of that, and don't use it at all. With one, cached `Connection` it would seem work. But with the pooled version, after one time, the pool would hang. You could "fix" this for a while by making a big `maxPoolSize`, but that's bad. You need to get Connections, get the PreparedStatements, use the statements, then close them and the parent Connection. You can't call `getConnection()` and drop the reference leaving the `Connection` unclosed.

Comment: i'm going to add this as an answer, just because i effed up above by saying the class is alright when it's not, and i wanna make sure other viewers see the problem.

Comment: @SteveWaldman - That explains it! I don't know why I didn't see this. I'm refactoring some old code, the utility class has a closeStatement method that is called when the statement is no longer needed. I can close the connection there.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't see it and led you on wild goose chases. Sorry! Anyway, let me know if things still go awry, but I doubt they will.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200676/discussion-between-ventsyv-and-steve-waldman).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `public PreparedStatement getPreparedStatement(String sql)` in your class is a `Connection` leak. Each time it is called, a `Connection` gets taken from the pool, but the the reference is dropped, so it is never `close()`ed and returned to the pool.

(I'm sorry in our comment thread above it took me so long to see this!)

When there is one shared `Connection`, it's no problem, one Connection stays checked out. But when, as you should with a pool, you checkout Connections just-in-time and don't cache them, you have to be sure to `close()` them when you are done.

Make sure that every call to `getConnection()` is matched by a call to `close()`. The easiest way to do this is

1. Don't use a getPreparedStatement(...)` function here, just work with Connections
2. Use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

```
try( Connection conn = myDBUtilityInstance.getConnection ) {
  try( PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement( sql ) ) {
    // do work here
  }
}
```